# Upload and Download images in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: php, azure, blob, azure-sdk-php

I am trying to upload an image from a HTML form to Azure Blob Storage using the Azure PHP SDK. The problem appears when I try to download the image. The result page can be seen at the bottom of the post.

I store the image using the temporary name and I think this is one of the two problems. I am not sure but the second problem is to when downloading the image. Do I have to convert it from the getContentStream() to image  ?

> $_FILES['driverLicenseFront']['tmp_name']

This is the html form to upload the image:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{path_to_controller}" data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="driverLicenseFront">Upload Driver's License(Front)</label>
        <input type="file" id="driverLicenseFront" name="driverLicenseFront">
    </div>
    <submit button>
</form>
```

In the controller I store the file like this:

```
// First check if there is a container
$blob = New Blob($_SESSION['userid']);
$blob->createContainerIfNotExists();
// Upload image to Azure Blob Storage
$content = fopen($_FILES['driverLicenseFront']['tmp_name'].'', "r");
$blob->uploadToContainer($content,'DriverLicenseFrontSide');
```

> **Blob** is my custom class to handle blobs

I need to download the file using a link:

```
<a href="../controller/blobs.php?blob_name=DriverLicenseFrontSide" target="_new">Download</a>
```

I catch the request in the controller:

```
if(isset($_GET['blob_name'])){
    $blob = New Blob($_SESSION['userid']);
    $blob->downloadBlob($_GET['blob_name']);
}
```

The function of the Blob class:

```
public function downloadBlob($blob_name){
    try {
        // Get blob.
        $blob = $this->blobRestProxy->getBlob($this->containerName, $blob_name.'.jpg');
        fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());
    }
    catch(ServiceException $e){
        // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
        // Error codes and messages are here:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    }
}
```

The result:

> ����JFIF,,���ICC_PROFILE�mntrRGB XYZ
>   �$acsp���-)�=ޯ�U�xB��ʃ9 descDybXYZ�bTRC�dmdd  ��gXYZ
>   hgTRC�lumi |meas �$bkpt �rXYZ �rTRC�tech �vued
>   ��wtptpcprt�7chad�,descsRGB IEC61966-2-1 black scaledXYZ
>   $����curv #(-27;@EJOTY^chmrw|�������������������������...

Comment: Hi Mitsos, have you solved your issue now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to add the `content-type` of response to convert the binary content to image content.

Try to add the following code in your `downloadBlob()` function.

```
$blob = $this->blobRestProxy->getBlob($this->containerName, $blob_name.'.jpg');
header("Content-Type:image/jpeg");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $blob_name . '"');
fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.